# Run powershell script as administrator and with a different user account

Tags: powershell, administrator, gpo

I need to use powershell to launch a powershell script as administrator and as a different user than the currently logged in user. This is for running some updates to GPO on several server machines.  The intent is for the script to prompt for credentials when it launches.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
 Start-Process 'powershell.exe' -Credential 'adminAccount' -ArgumentList '"file path\updateGPO.ps1" -Verb runAs'
```

This prompts for a password and will run the script with the specified account but doesn't run as administrator, giving an 'Access is Denied' error for administrator actions.  The new powershell window is missing the Administrator text in the title.

I also tried the following:

```
 $script = 'file path\updateGPO.ps1'
 Start-Process 'powershell.exe' -Credential 'adminAccount' -ArgumentList '-command &{start-process $script} -Verb runAs'
```

This launches a powershell window, writes no text, and immediately closes.

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: `-Verb` isn't a valid parameter when using `-Credential` on `Start-Process` (`Get-Command -Name Start-Process -Syntax`)

Comment: If your script requires elevation, use a self-elevating mechanism.  [Here's a github snippet example](https://gist.github.com/atao/a103e443ffb37d5d0f0e7097e4342a28)

Answer (score 1):

The comment from TheIncorrigible1 put me on the right track.

```
 Start-Process 'powershell.exe' -Credential 'adminAccount' -ArgumentList '"file path\updateGPO.ps1"'
```

At the top of the updateGPO.ps1 script I included the self-elevating mechanism.